# How to calculate the time for the solar disk to pass the horizon and transit's lines

Tags: the-sun, mathematics

For a given **date**, **longitude**, and **latitude**:

Popular apps and websites give the time when the sun's center or edge is on the horizon (i.e., the time of sunrise and sunset) or its transit (i.e., noontime), but I want to ask how to calculate the time needed for the **solar disk** to pass the **horizon's** line and the **transit's** line (preferably in c# or java)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for software source is not relevant.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think it's OK (and may even answer it) because it's ultimately asking for a formula, which can then be translated into C# or Java. In fact, the 2nd part of the question is answered here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24304/expression-for-length-of-sunrise-sunset-as-function-of-latitude-and-day-of-year and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/how-long-does-a-sunrise-or-sunset-take?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5):

The time it takes the sun to cross the horizon is given at:

- [Expression for length of sunrise/sunset as function of latitude and day-of-year](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24304/)
- [How long does a sunrise or sunset take?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/)

Re the time it takes to cross the transit line, this doesn't really answer your question, but, to a good approximation, the time varies between 128 seconds at the equinoxes and 140 seconds at the solstices, regardless of latitude or longitude.

More specifically, the formula is $\frac{128}{\cos (\text{dec})}$ seconds, where $\text{dec}$ is the Sun's declination. You can calculate the Sun's declination itself using the formulas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun

The calculation here is relatively simple:

- The Sun travels $360 \cos (\text{dec})$ degrees in a 24-hour day, where $\text{dec}$ is the Sun's declination
- When the Sun is transiting, the motion is perpendicular to the transit line (the Sun's motion is entirely in azimuth, not in altitude)
- Therefore, all of the Sun's angular motion translates to motion across the transit line; in contrast, the Sun rises and sets a (non-perpendicular) angle (except at tropical latitudes on the two days where the Sun passes directly overhead), so sunsets and sunrises take longer than $\frac{128}{\cos (\text{dec})}$ seconds
- Since the Sun has an angular diameter of 32 minutes or $\frac{8}{15}$ degrees, it takes $\frac{\frac{8}{15}}{360 \cos (\text{dec})}$ of a day for the Sun to cross the transit line
- Since a day is 86400 seconds, this works out to $\frac{128}{\cos (\text{dec})}$ seconds.

Caveats and nitpicks:

- I assume there are 86400 seconds between successive noons. This is incorrect for two reasons:

  - The time between noons is not exactly one day. The cumulative difference forms the [Equation of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time) but the day to day difference is quite small
  - The Earth's day is slightly longer than 86400 seconds, which is why we need [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)
- The Sun's angular diameter actually varies based on Earth's distance from the Sun, but 32 minutes is a good approximation
- I assume the Sun's altitude doesn't change while it's transiting. While this is a good approximation, the altitude does change slightly
- I assume the Sun's declination doesn't change while it's transiting. The change in declination is very small, so this is a reasonable assumption
- There are probably other assumptions I made implicitly that I am not noting here.
- Refraction is not an issue, since the motion we are discussing is azimuthal and not in altitude.
- I used the "one over cosine" form above to make things easier for non-mathematicians. The more compact form would use "secant".
- The calculations I did for this problem are disorganized, but available at: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-solar-transit.m