# What's the time in which the sun rises?

Tags: the-sun, time, sunrise

What's the time the sun takes in order to rise? (The time in which the solar disk crosses the horizon)
How does this time depend on local latitude and the sun's declination?
Assume that we're at sea level, and we ignore refraction and other atmospheric processes. (solar disk's altitude approximated with 0)

Comment: [This question should help.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/how-long-does-a-sunrise-or-sunset-take)